# a definite integral related to mean Gamma function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am looking for a closed form of the following integral 
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{a-1}\sin \theta dx}{x^2 - 2x\cos\theta + 1}$$

where $a>0$  and $0<θ<π$. I believe the answer is similar to the following form:

$$\frac{\pi\sin(a\theta)}{\sin(a+1)\theta}$$

In fact, it can be given as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n\theta}{n+a}$$
Thank you for all.

Comment: CAS yields an horrendous expression.